# how to convert String 23323.00 to Long

Tags: java, type-conversion, double, long-integer

```
String avgPageLoadTimeStr = row.get("avg_page_load_time");
Long avgPageLoadTime = Long.parseLong(avgPageLoadTimeStr);
```

For example :

```
avgPageLoadTimeStr = 52747.50;
```

How to convert `avgPageLoadTimeStr` to `Long`?

Comment: What happened when you use Long.parseLong()

Comment: You can use `Math.#round(double)`, to round the double to a long. Note that you will loose informations.

Comment: What is the time unit?

Comment: @JqueryLearner Using Long.parseLong("52747.50") causes a NumberFormatException.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes,But OP didnt mention anything So i asked

Answer (score 7):

`52747.50` is a floating point number. So you should first parse it to a floating point number and then round it to a long value:

```
String avgPageLoadTimeStr = row.get("avg_page_load_time");
double d = Double.parseDouble(avgPageLoadTimeStr);
long avgPageLoadTime = Math.round(d);
```

Depending on your needs you could also use `Math.floor()` or `Math.ceil()` before rounding it to a long value.

Comment: Note that `Math.floor` and `Math.ceil` return both a `double`.

Comment: +1 Note to OP, you want a `long` not a `Long`.  Just casting is enough in this case `long avgPageLoadTime = (long) Double.parseDouble(avgPageLoadTimeStr);`

Answer (score 2):

You will get a `NumberFormatException`, because "52747.50" is a floating point number.

Thus you can use `Double` to parse it and get the `long` value.

```
String avgPageLoadTimeStr = "52747.50";
Double doubleObj = new Double(avgPageLoadTimeStr);
long longValue = doubleObj.longValue();
System.out.println(longValue);
```

or simply

```
long longValue = (long) Double.parseDouble(avgPageLoadTimeStr);
```

Comment: You don't need to create a new Double object just to parse as a double.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes you're right. That's why I said "or simply..." :)